# Update from zurb foundation 5 to 6 in rails undefined method `to_h' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Yesterday I updated the gems for my rails-app. Now instead of foundation 5 I'm using version 6 with the

```
gem 'foundation-rails'
```

But since the update I get the following error everytime I try to load a page:

```
undefined method `to_h' for nil:NilClass
```

I tracked the error to the following line of Code in my Application.html.erb

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

If I erase that line the app works fine (yet some Styles, etc do not work due to the missing javascript).

I am actually clueless why I get this error and neither the search here nor google could be of any help. I also tried

```
rails g foundation:install
```

without sucess. I am using

```
ruby 1.9.3p-194
Rails 4.1.4
```

Since I didn't find any clue if foundation 6 needs a newer version I'm not sure whether the error has to do something with that or not.

Every hint is appreciated, Thanks!
Sven

Comment: You need to post the full error, with backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Ruby version, the `to_h` method is only available in Ruby version 2.1 or higher.

I assume somewhere in the code exists the construction like:

```
=> something_what_actually_can_be_nil.to_h
```

and expected result is empty hash (ruby 2.1):

```
=> nil.to_h
#> {}
```